# run 2 different versions of ffmpeg form same server

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compile, portable, source-code

I'm trying to run a second version of ffmpeg on a unix server without update or remove the old version.

In the server it's installed version 1.0.1, can I compile latest version of ffmpeg (current 2.5.4) on my machine (macbook) or can I use my raspberry (debian) to compile it and transfert the compiled source code to a certain directory on the server?

For example:
I would like to use server's ffmpeg with

`ffmpeg -i SOURCE_INPUT -OPTIONS_GO_HERE MY_GREAT_OUTPUT`

and use the newest version with

`/directory/of/ffmpeg/compiled/code/ffmpeg -i SOURCE_INPUT -OPTIONS_GO_HERE MY_GREAT_OUTPUT`

If this it is possible, how can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is to use a [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Just download, extract, and execute it.

You can move the binary wherever you prefer. To use it either:

- place it somewhere in your `PATH`,
- or navigate to the directory containing the binary and run `./ffmpeg`,
- or provide the full path to the binary, such as `/Users/Tenaciousd93/ffmpeg`.

If the static build does not provide what you need, such as `libfdk_aac` encoding support, then you can compile on the server as shown in [FFmpeg Wiki: OS X Compile Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX).

Comment: Thank you mate! I didn't see a static build on the official website. I'm trying with this static build. +1 :)

Comment: It worked! This is the correct answer, thank you very much!